# build project locally or remotely when using cloud hosting?

Tags: git, angular, google-app-engine, heroku, google-compute-engine

I have an Angular 2 (although my question applies to any framework/technology with a build process for deployment) project and I'm using google cloud VMs for hosting the app. Whenever I have a stable version, I follow the standard deployment process - I push the local files to github, pull from the remote VM and run the build scripts - although this doesn't seem a very nice process for a web page or web app in production, since it goes offline unless I redirect the calls to have no downtime. Also, when using App Engine or Heroku, the build takes too much time. But the thing is: if I just upload the built files without ignoring them in git, this makes the server respond instantly with the new files without downtime, expect that I don't see people doing this. 
My main question is why don't people do this often? Are there best practices for doing or not doing this and any documentation regarding this? I couldn't find anything related to this. 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you use a VM, you definitely can build on server. But, the point is, you have your development environment, your production env, but also your build environment. Presumably they're all different machines. So, build happens on a CI/CD - e.g. Jenkins. If you don't have it, your workstation is the build machine. So you test, build, and when the app is built, just deploy the compiled bundles.

Now, if you need to do some fancy stuff (if you do, you know how to), you *might* need the source on the production server. But in majority of cases, your app is a bunch of static files that you need to serve somehow. You could deploy by copying those bundles to a USB drive and going to a data center and copy to server, for all servers care.

Now, why people do or do not do this? Well, generally, bigger teams will have some sort of strict build/deploy procedure and if you don't wanna step on people's toes, you follow it. So it means there's a build server sometime. Even if your Google VM is that, it just means that the VM has two jobs - to build and to serve the app. Smaller teams, solo shops, you often don't care for any such overhead. I do suggest to automate the task into an npm script (so, `npm run deploy.prod` builds the app and pushes to google and maybe triggers some cache refresh or whatever), because that reduces mistakes. Regardless of where you build. But you likely do not need a separate build machine if you're running solo. Another reason can be that people deploy full stack apps, so they have to "build" the backend part, which is e.g. node, on the server anyway, so it's all part of a bigger process. But if it's just frontend, you don't have to.

So, it depends from team to team, from project to project.

Comment: Great, thanks for the detailed response Zlatko. It makes sense for me.